# ADO YAML Exit code of task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is there a way to capture the exit code/ return code of the previous task in ADO YAML?
Use Case: I want to be able to send an email notification if my DotNetCoreCLI@2 or MSBuild@1 task fails with a build error

Answer (score 2):

You can use `condition: failed()` to achieve this.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Run Tests'
  continueOnError: true
  inputs:
    command: 'test'

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  displayName: 'Publish Test Results'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
  inputs:
    testResultsFiles: '**/*.trx'

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Send email alert'
  condition: failed()
  inputs:
    targetType: 'filePath'
    filePath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\SendEmail.ps1
```

*please note my example .yaml does not include all the required task inputs*

Azure DevOps already has built in notifications for failed builds that can be configured. [See documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/notifications/about-notifications?view=azure-devops).